# MiniControllerFragment for MediaPlayer application as like Cast SDK

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, androiddesignsupport, android-music-player

I'm developing a MediaPlayer application which plays videos and want to show mini controller at the bottom of every screen while something is playing.

**Question**

I want to show mini controller at the bottom of every screen while something is playing, you can refer application like Spotify, google play, and other music applications.app 
MiniController that appear when the user navigates away from the current content page. The mini controller provides instant access and a visible reminder for the current mediaplayer is playing or not.

I just checked cast sdk codelabb and found [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#6). It has MiniControllerFragment which manages everything for cast session. Is there any MiniControllerFragment for mediaplayer application so I can show MiniController at bottom of every page when my application does play any video.

Please provide your valuable inputs on this.